# CakePHP: Using a variable on the layout when user is changing from page to page

Tags: php, cakephp, layout, cakephp-1.3

I've set a variable so it can be used from the controller to pass the value "current" to where the user browses to. It's working fine but I need a conditional programming to compensate with other pages. Let's say I browse to the page category, the category controller will pass the variable $current to my layout but hell went wrong we will have two links with that special id, e.g.

```
<li id="<?php echo "$current";?>"><?php echo $this->Html->link('Home', '/'); ?></li>    
<li id="<?php echo "$current";?>"><?php echo $this->Html->link('Category', '/categories'); ?></li>
```

I know a conditional required, can someone write that up? I'm not sure if I can use if else, because the other pages claim undefined variable. This is a bit tricky, maybe someone can do an ole working programming logic for this one?

**UPDATE:**
Hi I'm trying to make this work:

```
<?php if($current==NULL) {
                    <?php echo "<li id="current">";?>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Home', '/'); ?>
                    <?php echo "</li>"; ?>
                    }
<?php else: ?>{
                    <?php echo "<li>";?>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Home', '/'); ?>
                    <?php echo "</li>"; ?> 
              }
<?php endif ?>
```

I am getting an error on parsing right at the `<li> tags`. Does anyone know how to wrap up a `<li> tag` in PHP ?

P.S. I've tried all suggested possible solutions below, couldn't get it work for me. I thought this one currently I'm trying seem to be the easiest? thanks.

I'm not sure it will work though even after wrapping up the tags in PHP.

Comment: Are you doing it to highlight the current action in the list? If Yes then this might help  `$this->set('current', $this->params['controller'].'/'.$this->params['action']);`

Comment: Hi everyone, Yes, I'm trying to highlight the current page. I tried a few suggestions here, not successfully done yet, I'm trying with the helper at the moment. Thanks for the warm response and sorry for delay in update due to different timezone.

Comment: Hello people, this has been solved, I'm still trying to tick which answer contributes most to the success. Give me some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the other replies are correct, that you are trying to highlight the current page in the navigation, check out the following helper: http://www.richardathome.com/blog/cakephp-smarter-links

It extends the built in link helper to add two bits of functionality:

> -Links should automatically add a class to themselves when they are a)
>   pointing to a resource in the same
>   controller and b) pointing to
>   themselves.
>
> -Able to show/hide themselves.

The helper works fine, I've used it on a couple of projects.

**In response to update**

If that is your actual PHP, there are a couple of formatting errors. This line is invalid:

```
<?php echo "<li id="current">";?>
```

You need to escape the inner quotes, like so:

```
<?php echo "<li id=\"current\">";?>
```

But your braces are also a bit out of whack. Try the following:

```
<?php 
if($current==NULL) {
    echo "<li id=\"current\">";
    echo $this->Html->link('Home', '/');
    echo "</li>";
}
else {
    echo "<li>";
    echo $this->Html->link('Home', '/');
    echo "</li>";
}
?>
```

***Update 2***

As mentioned in the comment, I suspect $current is simply never actually NULL. In PHP an empty string is not NULL. I suggest instead of testing for NULL, test for emptiness.

The empty() function will return true if a value is null, 0, false, "", or an empty array. See here: http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

So your code becomes:

```
<?php 
if(empty($current)) {
    echo "<li id=\"current\">";
    echo $this->Html->link('Home', '/');
    echo "</li>";
}
else {
    echo "<li>";
    echo $this->Html->link('Home', '/');
    echo "</li>";
}
?>
```

Or even better (simply less duplication):

```
<?php 
if(empty($current)) {
    echo "<li id=\"current\">";
}
else {
    echo "<li>";
}
echo $this->Html->link('Home', '/');
echo "</li>";
?>
```

Comment: Hey, I've replied. Let me know if I didn't follow though.

Comment: Hi Botman, it isn't displaying the "content" style, however it isn't giving me any parse error now. It's just as if nothing changed. a good step forward I guess. What do you think is stopping it to display id="content" ? thanks..

Comment: Hi John, I suspect the problem is that $current is never null, instead even when you expect it to be null it is actually an empty string. Try adding var_dump($current); to your view. This will show you the data type and value of $current. I'll update my answer with the solution...

Comment: Hi Botman, wow, I got it done successfully. And thanks for the whole lots of information. I can't recall where went wrong as I tested with yours. I left out the correct layout. I'm not sure I kept changing and as far as I know your post is correct so I ticked. Moreover, tips from me; we may use the simplest way to highlight the tab by simply creating the "layout" for the controller. Only situation where consists of "member" areas we may want to use the conditions shown above, because it's quite insane creating a new layout for every view.

Comment: Hi John, yes, you really do not want to use a layout per view! That helper I linked earlier would take care of this for you. I.e. the conditional logic happens inside the controller so you don't need to write it/worry about it. The helper itself works out if or not it's an active link. If you do want to write conditional logic in your view, there are a lot of vars that might be of help, such as $this->here or $this->action. Put this in a view to see them all: <?php pr($this); ?>

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of CakePHP specifics, but you'd need something to the effect of:

```
$current = 'category';  // in controller

if($current=='category') { echo 'current' } // in view
```

for each link.

If it isn't already built in.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're trying to build a menu where the current page on the menu is styled differently? If this is not the case then my answer will need adapting to your particular case.

If this is the case, then Ross is quite correct, although I'd probably write it slightly differently to suit my personal aesthetics:

```
<li class="<?php ($current=='category') ? echo 'active' : echo 'inactive' ?>">
```

Note also that I used `class` rather than `id` as this would be the better way to write up the CSS. If you don't recognize the syntax, it's the *ternary operator* - a kind of shorthand for a conditional 'toggle'.

**Edit:**
There are some problems with logic (`$current==null`??), syntax, style and efficiency. I hope I have corrected these below.

Unless a string contains a variable or special character (newline etc.) you should use single (') quotes. PHP parses double (") quotes more slowly. Your use of double quotes in the first `<li>` line was syntactically wrong.

You had braces outside of `<?php ... ?>` blocks.

The whole code block can be enclosed in one pair of `<?php .. ?>`.

```
<?php
if($current) 
    {              
        echo '<li id="current">';
        echo $this->Html->link('Home', '/');
        echo '</li>';
    }
else
    {
        echo '<li>';
        echo $this->Html->link('Home', '/');
        echo '</li>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks but I chose the other answer because first; both of you and the other suggestions are the same except that maybe you have messed up with my intention, I would like that the home doesn't display current style if there's a variable $current existing. Anyway, thanks for the help, I have ticked 1 up vote as you deserved it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make a nav that can automatically know which page the user is on, and highlight the navigation (tab?) accordingly?

If that is the case, then I have some thoughts for you.

If you want the $current variable to be set for all controllers, then you probably want to put that in the app_controller. You may not have one, it isn't in the cake deployment by default. You would add it at CAKE_HOME/app/app_controller.php

it would look something like

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {
  function beforeFilter() {
    $this->set('current', $this->name . '.' . $this->action);
  }
}
?>
```

The alternative, which is something that I do in my apps, is to not use the variable $current, but to use the built in variables $this->name (the controller name) and $this->action ( the action name )

```
<?php $tmp = $this->here . '/'. $this->action; ?>
<li class="<?php ($tmp == '/') ? e('active-tab') : e('tab'); ?>">
    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Home', '/'); ?>
</li> 
<li class="<?php ($tmp == '/categories/index') ? e('active-tab') : e('tab'); ?>">
    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Category', '/categories'); ?>
</li>
```

The benefit is that you don't have to explicitly set the $category variable in each controller action. All the display logic is in the layout or views, where they should be. I like anything that lets me do less coding.

Comment: instead of

if($current == NULL)

try

if(isset($current) && !empty($current)) {

that's just nitpicking though.